# show product title in shopify product-template

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify, shopify-template

when I print this

`{{ product.metafields.custom.add_product_to_show }}`

I got this  gid://shopify/Product/8019965837629

how can I show the above product title and description?

This is not working
`{{ product.metafields.custom.add_product_to_show.title }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your Liquid Syntax. Metafields are a key:value store, namespaced. So in your case:

```
namespace is: custom  (wow, clever!!)
key is: add_product_to_show
```

So what you really want, is the **value** now, and that you can get as:

```
{{ product.metafields.custom.add_product_to_show.value }}
```